# Correct way to hash a unordered collection

Tags: hash

I am trying to find out the correct way to hash an unordered collection. In this collection elements may be repeated and the hash needs to reflect how many times an element appears. If we are unable to hash each element, sort the hashes and then hash the result (for example, because the elements are distributed between many machines which are unable to communicate all the data) what is the next best option?

I have seen three possible suggestions for combining the hashes of each element and I am wondering if they are valid in general or just for specific hash functions:

1. **XOR** - Will only work for sets which are guaranteed to not have duplicates as `a XOR a = 0`
2. **Addition** - Proposed as a better alternative to XOR since `a + a = a << 1` which seems a good fit as long as addition causing integer overflow wraps and equivalently the bit shift is a bitwise rotation
3. **Multiplication** - Another proposal which I have seen in this thread: [How to hash a set of elements](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35781/how-to-hash-a-set-of-elements) (not sure what benefits this might have over addition)

Are any of these a valid way to combine a collection of hashes without significantly increasing the chance of collision? Are they valid in general or only for cryptographic hash functions? If this isn't something that is supported by most hash functions, are there any specific hash functions which is designed to supports this use case?

Ideally I'd like to use a fast non-cryptographic hash function such as MurmurHash3, but I can't find any good resources that suggest any the above options are a valid way to combine hashes.

Comment: Are you looking to generate a cryptographical hash (e.g. one for which it is infeasible to find preimages or collisions, even given the details of the hash), or a statistical one (e.g. one for which different values are likely to hash differently, assuming that the hash values aren't chosen deliberately to cause collisions)?

Comment: what are your inputs? different length binary strings, fixed length strings, something else?

Comment: The inputs are binary data with no consistent length, but possibly sometimes with very small differences between them (e.g. single bits flipped out of thousands).

I'm not looking for a cryptographic hash, this is just to try to detect differences in data. No need to assume any malicious actors, the worst case scenario for my use case is accidentally finding a collision.

Comment: @LVA if collisions are the worst case scenario, you absolutely need to use a cryptographic hash function, and a good one (SHA2-256/512, SHA-3, Blake 2b). The canonical way to do this is with a sort then hash, or use a hash of sorted hashes. A Merkle Tree can be used to reduce communication bandwidth. http://danieloshea.com/2011/12/07/merkle-tree.html

Comment: @rmalayter Sorting isn't feasible in this case otherwise I would do exactly that. This is why I'm interested in other ways to combine hashes. If there's a cryptographic hash function that is both associative and commutative then I'll happily use it, but if there's not then I need to look other places even if it increases the probability of collision.

Comment: What is the use case, exactly? For example, if you only need to check whether a set you currently have is equal to some earlier hashed set, you could use a cryptographic accumulator. If either false negatives or false positives are allowed (but not the other) a bloom filter might suffice. Etc.

Comment: Having read this more carefully, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about non-cryptographic hashes. Addition of sufficiently strong hashes will not collide randomly and should work here.